# Fiber bundles: Hairy Ball vs. $S_2\times S_1$

Tags: differential-topology, fiber-bundles

This is more a request for explanations. There's one thing which makes me really mad:

On the one hand, it seems like I do have an intuitive understanding of the Hairy Ball theorem. I imagine an arrow of unit length (that's for simplicity - generally, of any nonzero length, of course) attached to each point of a sphere. I also insist that arrows attached to close points have close directions (usual metric and connection induced from 3d are implied). After few attempts to visualize, I assure myself that such configuration cannot be nowhere pathological.

In other words, it seems that the above described bundle - which could be obtained from the tangent bundle of $S_2$ by restricting the vectors to have unit norm (of course, the vector structure is lost within the fiber) - does not admit a global section.

On the other hand, nothing stops us from considering the $S_2\times U(1)$ trivial $G$-bundle, which certainly has a global section, e.g. $f(p) = \operatorname{const}$.

Moreover, to my understanding, in the second example we don't even need to stress that the section is a group. We can replace $U(1)$ with its torsor $S_1$, and the trivial bundle $S_2\times S_1$ will still admit a global section.

Now, the question. **Why exactly does thinking of $S_2$ with $S_1$ circles (in tangent planes) attached to each point fail as an illustration for the $S_2\times S_1$ bundle?**

Here's my attempt to answer. Let's go the other way around and start with $S_2 \times S_1$. On each of $S_1$ circles of those are attached to $S_2$ I can choose a point and declare that this is '$0$' (or '$1$', or any other label). Then, I define a global section $f(p)=$'$0$'. I even came up with an illustration. Here it is:

[image]

To any point of the ball I attach a circle. I don't draw it's plane as tangent to the sphere - because this is not required! Clearly, if at any point of $S_2$ the arrows look upwards, this defines a global (constant) section. If we now try to make those circles lie in planes tangent to $S_2$, clearly, at certain point we'll encounter a problem - the arrows will no longer be parallel in the usual sense. But this is just a defect of illustration.

Having said so many words, I would like to understand the difference between the two bundles rigorously:
\begin{alignedat}{9}
E_1 &= \text{Vectors of unit length in } T S_2\\
E_2 &= S_2 \times S_1 
\end{alignedat}

I guess, the difference should be in **transition functions**, since the base spaces and typical fibers are identical.

**Can anyone help me to figure out those?**

In still other words: **what's wrong with representing $E_1$ with the picture above?** Of course, it is weird, but we may draw the tangent spaces the way we want. Does it have to do something with connections? I would be surprised if so, since the ability to define a global vector field on the manifold is not related to ability to parallel transport vectors (one doesn't need Christoffels to define the Lie derivative).

Answer (score 1):

The circle bundle of the sphere derived from the tangent bundle isn't $S^2 \times S^1$ topologically; you can think of a normalized tangent vector as a second point on the sphere with a perpendicular vector from the origin, and adding the cross product will yield you a third one and an oriented orthonormal basis.  The space of orthonormal bases is homeomorphic to the group $SO(3)$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^3 \not\cong S^2 \times S^1$.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! That's a great way to think about this construction.

Comment: It's a good picture of $E_1$, but one way to see they're not equivalent is it would mean you could <i>specify coordinates</i> in all of $E_1$ as $(a, b): a\in S^2, b\in S^1$, in a smooth way. If so pick the points $0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2$ on $S^1$ in each tangent plane on each point of $S^2$: so four tangent vectors at right angles to each other, which is really four perpendicular sections.  Now you have invented consistent global cardinal directions -- north south, east, west-- at every point on the surface of the earth.  But as it is we have to make exceptions for the north and south poles.

Comment: I say you could specify coordinates because that's using a (counterfactual) diffeomorphism $E_1\cong S^2\times S^1$.